# Can a personal adjective be categorized as a noun phrase?

Tags: pronouns, nouns, adjectives

In '[File Change Semantics and the Familiarity Theory of Definiteness](http://www.jimpryor.net/teaching/courses/hyper/heim1983.pdf)' by Irene Heim, she calls 'its' in 'Every cat ate its food' a type of definite NP. Could a possessive adjective be classified as a noun phrase???

> 2. Every cat ate its food.
> 3. John didn't see a cat.
>
> (2) has a reading where "its", a personal pronoun, i.e. ***a type of
>   definite NP***, functions as a so-called "bound variable pronoun" and
>   doesn't refer to any particular cat.

Comment: Yes, she's right. Personal pronouns are definite NPs (or DPs).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to match up your question with your examples.  The "its" in "its food" is neither an adjective nor a noun phrase.  It is a definite determiner.  The usual analysis is that this determiner is formed by combining a noun phrase with the "-s" ending.  The definite pronoun "it" is a noun phrase, so "its" is simply a special case where the noun phrase "it" has been suffixed with "-s".

Full noun phrases, not just definite pronouns, can take this same "-s" suffix to form such noun phrases as "[NP [NP the man]'s hat]", "[NP [NP a girl who I used to know]'s car]", "[NP [NP [NP the hat]'s brim]'s edge]".

Comment: So Heim's claim of "its" being a type of definite noun phrase is correct? Is it because she is saying 'type of' definite noun phrase? Not really a genuine definite noun phrase, but 'type of' definite noun phrase ....

Comment: No, "its" is not a definite noun phrase.  It is a definite determiner within a noun phrase, which is formed by suffixing "-s" to a noun phrase, which need not be definite.  "A man's hat" is a definite noun phrase formed by combining the definite determiner "a man's" with the noun "hat", and the definite determiner is formed by combining the indefinite noun phrase "a man" with the suffix "-s".  (I confess that I didn't read the Heim reference.)

Comment: I see, Greg. I see it. Thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Heim's expression is ambiguous, but I think the sense is, if not exactly clear, at least readily recoverable. What Heim means is that the *it* piece of *its* is a pronoun standing for a  "definite" NP, yet has no specific referent—it refers to no particular cat.

I see three strategies for rescuing the expression:

1. *Its* is a typo for *it*, *or*
2. *Its* is considered under the aspect "inflected form of *it*", *or*
3. *Its* is an awkward way of mentioning a morphological component while  preserving reference to a constituent actually present in the utterance.